# Unity 3D Android Project not building

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build my Unity 3D Project with android and I'm getting these following errors:

If anyone could please help me. In my plugins I have an AdMob folder but it works fine because it worked for a past project.

```
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x0021f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:182 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00065] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89 
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()


Build completed with a result of 'Failed'
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_171\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/unity3d/ads/BuildConfig;

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
]
stdout[
NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.
If you are using NDK, verify the ndk.dir is set to a valid NDK directory.  It is currently set to C:\Users\Drive Along\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle.
If you are not using NDK, unset the NDK variable from ANDROID_NDK_HOME or local.properties to remove this warning.

The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAdmoblibReleaseLibrary
:preparePlayServicesAds1500Library
:preparePlayServicesAdsBase1500Library
:preparePlayServicesAdsIdentifier1501Library
:preparePlayServicesAdsLite1500Library
:preparePlayServicesBasement1501Library
:preparePlayServicesGass1500Library
:prepareSupportCompat2531Library
:prepareSupportV42531Library
:prepareUnityAdapter2100Library
:prepareUnityAdsLibrary
:prepareUnityAdsSdk21Library
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:javaPreCompileRelease
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseNdk NO-SOURCE
:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:lintVitalRelease
:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeReleaseAssets
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
29 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 9 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Comment: Did you try the suggestions in the error message to address the `NDK is missing a "platforms" directory.` error?